# How to remove current line highlighting in WebStorm 11

Tags: webstorm

How do I get rid of highlight of current line?

The color looks exactly like highlight text color.

I found something about "caret" but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK so the correct thing is called "Caret Row"

Settings -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General -> Editor -> Caret row

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers mentioned, just follow this image and unselect the `background` for the `Caret row` from the `settings` menu.

[image]